# Rust - Why is Rc not Send in the following scenario?

Tags: rust

A type can be `Send` if it can be **moved from one thread to another safely** (according to the Rust book). I understand the non-atomic increment/decrement that `Rc` does but I don't understand how that would make it unsafe in the following example:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::{thread};

fn main() {
     // x1 initialized - count = 1
    let x1 = Rc::new(5);

    // x1 cloned - count = 2. No other threads exist to cause issues due to non-atomic increment
    let x2 = Rc::clone(&x1); 

    // x2 moved from thead-main to thread-other. This move occurs before the thread actually runs
    // x2 in main cannot be used after this point and drop wont be called on it. 
    // This is a move so no increment/decrement takes place.
    // main can't move forward unless the move is complete so drop/decrement wont happen
    thread::spawn(move || {

        // Technically "moving" x2 from thread-main to thread-other did not cause problems
        // so why is `Rc` not `Send`?
        println!("{:?}", x2);
    });
}
```

As far as I understand `Send` only talks about the move being possible, since no moves cause decrement/increment why is Rc not send?

Comment: Your code would exhibit a race-condition on unsynchronized memory modification when `x1` and `x2` get dropped.

Comment: Presumably you know about Arc? (Arc<T> will implement Send and Sync as long as the T implements Send and Sync.)

Answer (score 6):

You are asking why the compiler does not prove that your code is safe. This is impossible. It's impossible for a compiler to prove any non-trivial semantic property of a turing-complete program (Rice's theorem). Yes, you may be able to prove it in your trivial example, but outside of that, it would be horrendously difficult.

So the compiler has to simplify and be pessimistic.

`Send` is a trait, operating at the type-system level, with no knowledge about the run-time environment. And `Rc`, having to assume the worst, does not implement it. Yes, it would be safe, if you pass over all the references together. But there's no way of proving that you are doing that in the general case.

If you just have one reference, you can use `Rc::unwrap`. Otherwise, you can muck with `unsafe`, which is the escape hatch for dealing with things that the compiler can't prove is safe. But then it's up to you to ensure that the code is safe.

---

Also as a note, this code would be unsafe. Variables are dropped when they go out of scope - for `x1`, that would be after the thread spawns, which means two threads would access it at the same time. But there's a simple fix for that - drop `x1` beforehand.